# Java-WebKit: EventSource object can not be created?

Tags: java, javascript, webkit, server-sent-events

Our web application uses `EventSource` for server-sent events. In FireFox and Chrome everything's fine and everything works.

However, when I try to run a simple JAVA-application using WebKit (NetBeans JavaFX sample application "WebViewBrowser") the `onmessage` handler seems not to get called.

I tried to run the w3schools [EventSource sample page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_sse) and get the same result:
FireFox and Chrome is fine. The sample "WebViewBrowser" is not.

Does anyone have any idea why?!

**Update 1**

(see comment below)
I just noticed, that the constructor func `EventSource` is available but the object is not created.

```
var eventSrc = new EventSource('...');
// eventSrc is undefined now
```

I'm using JavaDK 1.7.0 (51)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of WebKit is too old, is the first thought that comes to mind. (E.g. I've never got EventSource to work in PhantomJS 1.x for that reason.)

Try having your code connect to http://html5test.com/ and study the result (If that page says you do have EventSource support in your WebKit instance, let us know as it would mean something else is up.)

Comment: The result shows: "Server-Sent Events" as supported. However, when I try to create an `EventSource` object with `new EventSource` it is `undefined` afterwards (`firebug`ed). Though the constructor func for `EventSource` seems to be existent.

Comment: Btw, I just tried the latest JavaDK 1.7.0_51 .. still the same issue.

Comment: @SamuelTee I guess html5test.com must just look for existence of `window.EventSource` and not try actually constructing it.

Comment: @SamuelTee From a Chrome console, if I try `var es = new EventSource();` I get an error about the missing required parameter, and `es` is `undefined`. However if I try `var es = new EventSource('not-there');` then I get an error (about bad MIME type) but `es` is a real object. (Sorry, I'm out of ideas.)

Comment: Thanks anyway. The odd thing is that I get no error at all. It just doesn't work.

Comment: Additional Note: This answer _seems_ valid. I tried using JDK8 and was able to create (and use to some degree) an `EventSource` object.